# How can i configure one-to-many relationship in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mapping, ef-core-2.0

I want to configure a **one-to-many** relationship in **Ef core**. As you see I have a class for **order** and the other one for **OrderItems**.
I do it when I use NHibernate.of course, I consider orderItem class as ValueObject.But I want to do it using EF Core.

```
public class Order 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDateTime { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem  
{
    public string BookId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public Order Order { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: add foreignKey to Order field of OrderItem class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple demo like below:

1.Model:

```
public class Order
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDateTime { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int OrderItemId { get; set; }//you need to define a primary key for OrderItem model
    public string BookId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public Order Order { get; set; }

}
```

2.DbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                    .HasMany(c => c.OrderItems)
                    .WithOne(e => e.Order);
    }
}
```

3.Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbContext")));
```

4.appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
   "MyDbContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" 
}
```

5.Run command line on Package Nuget Manager:

```
PM>add-migration init
PM>update-database
```

Comment: Thanks.If Order is an aggregate root so OrderItems is a collection of ValuObject OrderItem.It seems there is no way to map OrderItems without a primary key.

Comment: of course yes, but I can't because of low reputation.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, this is pretty clear @Rena. Any decent source to learn modeling like this related to .NET and Entity?

Answer (score 3):

you should define meta data `[ForeignKey]` with type of primary key in order entity. after that ef core automatically set in db by your chosen name

```
public class Order 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }    

    [ForeignKey(nameof(OrderId)]
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public long OrderId { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Model

```
 public class Order     {
            public long Id { get; set; }
            public long CustomerId { get; set; }
            public DateTime OrderDateTime { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
      }

public class OrderItem

{  
    [Key]
    public int OrderItemId { get; set; }
    public string BookId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public long OrderId{get;set;} // ForeignKey OrderId
    [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }

}
```

// open PackageManager console

```
PM>add-migration "orderItem changed"
PM>update-database
```

Comment: Thanks.of course, this is a solution and I did that. But I don't want to define a primary key. Because I think Order Items are a collection of value objects.as I said I do that by NHibernate.So it seems it's impossible in EF Core? Isn't It?